# High Load Average But CPU And Memory Are Not Used NGINX

Tags: linux, nginx, php, centos7

First of all I want to explain what I am using the server for.

This server is used to deliver downloadable files. Specially video games which I upload to the server and then users can download it through form action. Below is the link to the source where the download file is requested.

The problem I am facing is that I have Intel Core i7 8 Cores 12 GB Ram dedicated server. And whenever I let my users download files through the server it starts generating high load average and the server is then unable to fetch downloads through the PHP pages that I created it for.

I have also attached my `Nginx.conf` and other screenshots so do check them out.
And one more thing: whenever I restart my nginx its gets ultra fast despite the load average but then again slows down after a minute.

You can check here this is the source where the download file is requested

worldofpcgames.net/fairy-fencer-f-advent-dark-force-free-download/

***HERE IS MY NGINX->***

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 8;
worker_rlimit_nofile 5000;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 3000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /mnt/www/html;
    index index.php;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
        location /protected {
            root /mnt/www/html;
            secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
            secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr enigma";

            if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
            if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
    error_page 403 /blocked.html;
        }
}

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

***And HERE IS THE NGINX error log ->***

And one more thing i havent configured my PHP or Mysql at all. I just installed them and did the basic settings such as changed the user and owner group to nginx. and listen

HERE are the screenshot of TOP->
[image: top output]

atop -c
[image: atop -c]

And i am on Centos7
So please help me out

---

Sorry here is the nginx.conf couldn't link above because I don't have reputation points
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByamFYoTQ6KRRFpnUWJ3VGNxUEE

Comment: The problem is obviously with the disk `/dev/sdc`. It can't keep up with all the demand placed on it. That might be because the drive is defective or it might be because you have more traffic than it can handle.

Comment: @MichaelHampton when you say "obviously", perhaps you could point out which piece of information led you to this, to help others who'd like to learn.

Comment: @Tim It's so blatantly a problem that `atop` was kind enough to print it in red text. So, yes, it's obvious where the problem lies. What's not obvious is the underlying cause; as I mentioned there are a couple of possibilities.

Comment: @Tim it would be a combination of the high I/O wait and the red line that says `sdc` is at 100% utilization.

Comment: Also the fact that so many nginx process are in a `D` state, which is waiting on I/O.

Comment: So whats the fix and the drive is not faulty for sure, they are brand new.

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean it *can't* be faulty. You may want to grab SMART data from the drive via something like `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`. In addition, we don't know your LVM configuration, and you might be running a linear logical volume that's only allocating to the first disk and thus only reading from it. That would be more of a capacity planning problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your disk `iowait` (sdc). Look at the red lines of your screen shot called `atop -c`. This would cause high load average but low cpu usage. What is your lvm configuration?

update: @MichaelHampton pointed this out before me, in the comments.